# How to change an object's fields from an activity it was not initialized in

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop

This is my first time building a complex android app so I apologize if this is a vague question (please ask me to expand!) but I'm a little lost on how I should design/implement my application.

To make it easier, say I have a list of cars to choose from in the main activity.

Once a car is selected, it will take me to its specific settings page in another activity (the master/detail flow activity).

What I'm thinking of doing is the following:

- Create a class for car with all of its fields as the various settings
- Create a list of them in MainActivity
- Once a car is selected, pass that specific car to the master/detail flow activity using `intent`
- From here I'm a little confused, but I think that in the 2nd activity depending on the settings the user selects, the car in the list in the MainActivity will have its fields changed even though it was changed in another activity?

Is this the best way to approach changing settings for a list of objects initialized in the MainActivity, from another activity? I'm mostly confused on if I'm allowed to do that 4th point.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the object to the first activity and update your list with the new data.

Start the detail activity with the `startActivityForResult` and then in your second activity after doing the modifications:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putSerializableExtra("result", theObject);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And then, in the first activity use the `onActivityResult` method to retrieve the modified object.

Comment: OK that makes sense.. and this is assuming my class would have to implement Serializable and not Parcelable right? Also, where would I use the onActivityResult method in my first activity? 
Would I put it right after the startActivity(intent); in my first activity?

Comment: Yes sir, the easy way is to implement Serializable in your data class. You can `Override` the `onActivityResult` where you prefer cause it's an `Override` method and it will be executed when the second activity `finish()`

Comment: Mm I haven't finished trying it out yet, I'll update you if I finish it